# Accessing Active Directory From a Computer Not Part of the Domain With C# and Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory

I am trying to access Active Directory from a computer that is not part of my Domain. I am using C# for the most part with a Powershell script to get the information I need.

The script I need to run is simple and is as follows:

```
string script = "Import-Module activedirectory \n" +
            "(Get-ADUser -Filter * -Server 192.168.1.20| ConvertTo-XML " +
            "-NoTypeInformation).Save(\"C:\\data\\ad.xml\")";
```

I have some C# code to run the script and it then it reads a created file and gathers what information I need it to a Text Area (not shown).

```
RunScript(script);

private void RunScript(string scriptText)
{
    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

    runspace.Open();

    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);

    pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

    pipeline.Invoke();

    runspace.Close();
}
```

Eveything works fine as long as the computer is part of the Domain, but my issue arises when I try to pass the same query from outside the domain.

I have tried adding the Credential parameter to the script, but pipeline.Invoke() will not accept a parameter that requires user input. Any advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Windows Server 2003, AD default security policy is to require a secure channel for user authentication (so user credentials aren't passed in clear text).  The client computer uses it's domain credentials to set up that secure channel.  You'd have to intentionally weaken the domain security policy to be able to authenticate from a non domain-joined computer.

Comment: So there is no way to query AD from a remote computer? I can run the script from a remote Powershell with the -Credential PSCredential parameter specified. But I can't do it from inside C#?

Comment: I don't think you can do it directly.  You have to talk to the DC via a secure channel, and only a domain joined computer can do that.